# Define custom color_palette in Julia Plots package

Tags: julia, color-palette, plots.jl, color-blindness

I am currently using Plots package in Julia with pyplot as the backend. I can choose color_palette and make plots by

```
pyplot(color_palette=:delta)
Plots.plot(x, y)
```

What is the syntax to define and use a custom color palette according to, for example, Okade and Ito below, for color-blind-friendliness? Thanks!
[image: Okade and Ito color palette]

Comment: You can see an example here https://github.com/baggepinnen/Savefig.jl/blob/069c231746a03c6902d17e1ea43fb66577d9d840/src/Savefig.jl#L12

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just pass a Vector of RGB - see the docs here https://docs.juliaplots.org/latest/colors/#Misc-1 But that particular palette is actually built into Plots - so you can get it by specifying `theme(:wong2)` before plotting, it will change the palette and color gradient for the duration of the session.

Comment: Thanks! Was able to define OIcolor = [RGB(35. 70. 90.) ...] and invoke color=OIcolor in plots.
Somehow my environment doesn't have :wong2. Invoking cgradients() yielded 6 palettes: :blues, :viridis, :pu_or, :magma, :plamsa, :inferno

Comment: Yes that functionality seems to have gone missing - you can always use `theme(:wong2)` though

Comment: Note: theme(:wong2) works well in Julia 1.4.1. It did not work in Julia 1.2.0, as "Unknown key: colorgradient" error was thrown.

Comment: @Jen-FengHsu I think that's an issue with version mismatches between PlotUtils and PlotThemes, not a general julia-1.2 thing